# Файловый доступ в облако для офисов

Tags: облако

Добрый день. Стоит задача между 50 филиалами по России организовать файловый доступ. Файлы обычно это сканы, вердовские документы и разные таблицы. Необходимо что бы каждый сотрудник в офисе имел доступ к этому хранилищу а так же что бы был разграничен доступ у определенных сотрудников к папкам или файлам. Кто то видит кто то может редактировать а кто то может удалять. Файлов новых за день может набегать 50-100 Мб.

Так как скорость в филиалах может быть разная и соответственно организовывать у себя в офисе ftp или что то подобное не вариант. Нужно облачное решение с разграничением по правам доступа. Еще главная особенность это стабильная работа. Ну плюс это удобный и понятный интерфейс.Организация готова платить за такие решения.

Что тут можно сделать и какие пути решения вы тут ведите? Я остановился на яндекс диске гугл диске и дропбоксе. Гугл диск ещё и позволяет редактировать онлайн документ.

Comment: Гугл Диск + Гугл Докс

Comment: А как быть с правами? Там же нельзя поставить права на папку или скрыть папку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте OwnCloud. Простота установки на Линукс вас поразит. Возможна работа через web-интерфейс, а также имеется клиент под все существующие сегодня ОС. Имею двухлетний личный опыт использования, проект активно поддерживается.

[ссылка на описание](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OwnCloud)

Comment: Это лучшее решение которое я смог предложить. Но тут есть несколько минусов клиента owncloud он как то странно себя везет когда удалить папку а потом создать ей. Она появляется 2 раза и с одинаковым названием. Что как то странно для винды которая позволила так сделать. Еще один минус что у всех пользователей нельзя изначально указать одну папку домашнюю т.е. к каждого своя, тут конечно можно выкрутится путем создания расшаренных папок. Но ownloud это самое лучшее что может быть на сегодняшний день.

Comment: Кстати webdav как то странно дружит с кодировками. Пришлось использовать NetDrive он самый лучший webdav клиент.

Answer (score 1):

Если хотите на своем сервере, попробуйте покурить [WebDAV](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) или протянуть самбу в интернет (имхо первый вариант лучше.)

Comment: канал узкий, 5 Мбит всего лишь. Поэтому кажись лучше смотреть в сторону облачных хранилищ...

Answer (score 0):

Если между филиалами есть VPN и можно пустить трафик до файлопомойки через него то наверное лучше всё-таки samba. Не знаю как WebDAV, но samba достаточно гибко настраивается и интегрируется в win-инфраструктуру (у вас ведь она?). Сам сервер самбы можно поднять не только на windows, но и на GNU/Linux или FreeBSD.

Comment: Представьте что 50 филиалов начнут по VPN тянуть файлы с нашего офиса. Тормоза будут ужасные.

Comment: В облаках не получится гибко настроить права доступа (наверное, может где-то оно есть). С AD не проинтегрируешься. Если забить на всё это то можно конечно и облако заюзать.Ещё как вариант: аренда виртуалки/сервера в ДЦ (или в том-же облаке, по сути не велика разница). Ну и уже там VPN со всеми филиалами, и хоть самба, хоть вебдав, хоть owncloud через веб-интерфейс. Но придётся платить конечно-же.